# Can I disable syncing when WordPress users create accounts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a CiviCRM database on my WordPress site. When new members sign up for our organization they create a CiviCRM account via the profile. Later they create accounts in WordPress to access certain members-only sections of the site. I do not want these WordPress accounts to sync. How can I disable that feature? I am now getting many duplicate records (and I need to allow duplicates as we have individual records -- children -- with same email -- parent).

Answer (score 1):

You can unhook CiviCRM's hook callbacks like this:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_disable_civi_user_sync' );
function my_disable_civi_user_sync() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'civi_wp' ) ) return;
    remove_action( 'user_register', array( civi_wp()->users, 'update_user' ) );
    remove_action( 'profile_update', array( civi_wp()->users, 'update_user' ) );
    remove_action( 'deleted_user', array( civi_wp()->users, 'delete_user_ufmatch' ), 10 );
}
```

Disclaimer: this is untested code. You may need to hook into a later action, e.g. `init`.

Answer (score 0):

When members sign up you can give them the option of creating a WordPress account at that time. It is in the Advanced Settings of the profile. You can give the option or require account creation.

This will not stop the sync but should reduce the number of duplicates.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

From reading between the lines of your question, I think you're taking the wrong approach. Rather than not syncing the contacts, why not prevent deduplication unless the names, DOBs, and the emails are the same? This is doable through the interface, allows you to have genuine matches between accounts where correct, and meets the need you stated.